# Delphi 10 64bit debug boolean properties issue

Tags: debugging, 64-bit, delphi-10-seattle

I wrote a 64 bit program and compiled for release.  Ran the program and found an anomaly in the code so I switched to debug mode so I could trace through the code.  I did a build and then "Run with debugging".  I got an Access Violation on OldCreateOrder.  I changed the form to text view and removed the OldCreateOrder property from the form.  "Run with debugging", again.  I got another Access Violoation on another boolean property: AButton.ParentFont.  I removed that property, still in form text view.  Another run, another Access Violation on another boolean property.

One thing I noticed, when I switched from text view back to form view, all the removed properties were restored, and I still get the Access Violations.

Running in 64 bit Release, 32 bit debug and release work fine.

I'm stumped.

Is there something I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling JCL's jdbg insertion into the project solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you are subject to the defect in the 64 bit compiler that was fixed in update 1. The defect is the subject of this Quality Portal issue: [RSP-12512](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-12512).

You must update to the latest version, or at least apply the hotfix that addresses the compiler defect. As I understand the Embarcadero licensing policy, if you don't have an update subscription, you are not entitled to receive any updates. I believe however that if that is the case then you will be able to apply the hot fix.

- [Delphi Win64 Compiler hotfix for 10 Seattle Professional (Beta)](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/30428).
- [Delphi Win64 Compiler hotfix for 10 Seattle Enterprise (Beta)](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/30429).

Comment: If this is not the problem then I suggest that you provide more details in your question. Provide a means for us to reproduce your problem. A [mcve]. Finally, when you report errors, don't describe them. Quote them verbatim. Use copy/paste to get the complete text of the error message.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I upgraded to subscription update 1, but the issue persists.  I then considered 3rd party add-ons.  I use JCL, so I disabled all the options for jdbg insertion.  That solved my issue.

Comment: I think it should stay because someone else might have the same issue and find the answer here.  This is a place to find answers, afterall.